# SQL Substring a range of data

Tags: sql

I want to select out just the email address using SubString.

Here is my column data:

```
[{"IsPrimary":false,"Address":"test@gmail.com","Type":"Other"}]
```

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(EmailJson, CHARINDEX('ess":"', EmailJson)+6, CHARINDEX('","Type', EmailJson)) From Respondents
```

Problem is that it isn't working the way I thought substring would work. I expected it to give me a range of characters. For example I want substring to return a range of characters like 5-10. The way this substring works is that I establish the start and then how long I want it to be from the start position.

How can I alter my query to just return them email only from the column.

Comment: SUBSTRING takes a start index and a length, not two indexes

Comment: If that really ugly structure is consistent, you could split it on the comma first, and then split on the colon to pull out whichever elements you want.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... things like string manipulation are **highly vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: Why are you storing JSON in a database? Why not just split this into three columns?

Comment: If you are using Postgres, you could upgrade to 9.3 which has some nice JSON functions that would directly support that. @michaelb958 why not? It's similar to storing XML in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the above comments that this is not an elegant way of doing it but if you really need to use substring then have a look at the below.

I have changed this to work with oracle because that is what I have available and I am unsure what you are using but you should be able to get the idea from it.

```
SELECT substr(EmailJson, (instr(EmailJson,"Type":"Other"', 'ess":"')+6), (instr(EmailJson,"Type":"Other"', '","Type') - (instr(EmailJson,'ess":"')+6))) From Respondents;
```

Comment: "*no elegant way*" depends on the DBMS being used. In Postgres this would be: `select json_extract_path_text(emailJson, 'Address')`

Comment: This worked. Its a one off event. I am doing this to remove the JSON permanently. Inserting just the email back into the db.